# Scala-Groupby Array[(String, Array[String])] by the String

Tags: scala

I have a structure, `Array[(String,Array[String])]`
It contains similar Strings
eg:

```
    "A",["b","bc","f","df"]
    "B",["b","df","sef","g"]
    "A",["s","rg","rg"]
    "B",["f","dfv","x"]
```

I want it to be grouped together as,

```
    "A",["b","bc","f","df","s","rg","rg"]
    "B",["b","df","sef","g","f","dfv","x"]
```

Is there a way I can do this?
(new to scala)

Comment: The downvote is probably because of: [noattempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), no [mcve] (the input had to be adjusted in order to be usable in an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ ++ _).distinct)
```

Example:

```
val input = Array(
  ("A", Array("b","bc","f","df")),
  ("B", Array("b","df","sef","g")),
  ("A", Array("s","rg","rg")),
  ("B", Array("f","dfv","x"))
)

val result = input
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ ++ _).distinct)

for ((c, a) <- result) println(c + " -> " + a.mkString(","))
```

output:

```
A -> b,bc,f,df,s,rg
B -> b,df,sef,g,f,dfv,x
```